# I accidentally exited out of the popup where app inventor asked for the path to adb

Tags: android, adb, app-inventor

How can I get it back again so I can put the right path into it? I think this is the reason that app inventor wont connect to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jason's Troubleshooting ADB Path http://android.jwtyler.com/Tutorials.html

It covers resetting the path.

and

This conversation has a better way to get the path set on Windows
http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/forum/#topic/getting-started-with-app-inventor/dRiJXp5kyBA/discussion

and this covers Linux
http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/forum/#topic/getting-started-with-app-inventor/vSP0UyBvDog/discussion

Answer (score 0):

and

If you *lost* the location, the instructions at Install the App Inventor Extras Software in http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/setup/ should help. The locations may be changed a bit, the dev team just updated the installer.

Comment: The new path http://groups.google.com/group/appinventor/browse_thread/thread/abd9e73be3f4311d#

Answer (score 0):

You have to exit the block editor, and then restart it.  (At least for me that was the only option.)

Also, the fact that my system couldn't find ADB was because I didn't have it installed!!  Once I installed ADB, the pop up didn't show up.